# Stack bar chart animated data change

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/ACUqRZqBK9lrF4dfFeqp?p=preview

It's a D3 chart in Angular

The 'Update' button updates the data in the graph and adjusts the axis

How can I animate the bars when the data changes.

I sort of have it working but have commented out the code in the plunker becasue it stops the axis from working and animated each block separatly and I wanted to animate the column as one if possible and obviously have the axis.

```
this.layersBar.selectAll('rect')

    .data((d:any)=>{
        return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('y', (d:any)=>{
        return this.y(d[1])
    })
    .attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
        return this.x(d.data.date)
    })
    .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth())
    //.attr('height', 0)
    //.transition()
    .attr('height', (d:any, i:any)=>{
        return this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1]);
    })

    .on("mouseover", ()=>{
        d3.select('.chart-tooltip').style("display", null)
    })
    .on("mouseout", ()=>{
        d3.select('.chart-tooltip').style("display", "none")
    })
    .on("mousemove", (d:any)=>{
        d3.select('.chart-tooltip')
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 15 + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 25 + "px")
            .text(d[1] - d[0]);
    });

    d3.transition(this.svg).select(".y-axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(this.yAxis);

    d3.transition(this.svg).select(".x-axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(this.xAxis);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is simply the method `on`.

There are two different methods in D3 with the same name: `selection.on` is the method that you used here, with listeners as `mouseover` or `mouseout`. However, there is also `transition.on`, which doesn't have `mouseover` or `mouseout` as listeners.

When you use `transition()` it returns a transition selection. Because of that, the `on` you have afterwards is a `transition.on`, not a `selection.on`, and you get the error:

> unknown type: mouseover

The solution is quite simple: break your selection (and name it!):

```
bars.transition()
    .attr('height', (d:any, i:any)=>{
        return this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1]);
    });

bars.on("mouseover", ()=>{
    //etc...
```

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pQ9HdlSGvMymfreCfg6f?p=preview

Comment: Thank you again Gerardo. It is possible to animate the whole column in one go and not animate each block in the column